# Matrix factorisation of vote share data

Tags: matrix-factorisation

Consider a matrix, $\mathbf{V}$, where each row corresponds to one of $m$ electoral district and each column corresponds to one of $n$ candidates or political parties. Each element, $V_{ij}$, is the proportion of votes cast in district $i$ for party $j$.

Now imagine taking leave of your senses and deciding to carry out a low-rank matrix factorisation of $\mathbf{V}$. It turns out that regular non-negative matrix factorisation minimising generalised KL-Divergence will preserve the row and column sums in the approximation[1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379507001115), so where the rank of your factorisation, $k$, is less than $n$, it's straightforward to find $k$ latent variables for each electoral district that describe contributions to the share of each party's vote in that district.

My questions:

1) Are there any obvious reasons I shouldn't be doing this?

2) Is there a sensible interpretation of these $k$ variables?

3) Is there a more canonical method for factorising matrices like this? Or a more canonical method for finding latent variables for data like this?